# How to force LineLegend to be independent from the plot

Tags: plotting, legending

I want to design the plot legends independent of the plot style I use in `ListLinePlot`. So I do:

```
colors = ColorData[97, "ColorList"];

fontsize = 20;    
leg = LineLegend[{colors[[5]], {Black, Dotted}}, {Style["simulation", 
        FontFamily -> Times, fontsize, SingleLetterItalics -> False], 
       Style["experiment", FontFamily -> Times, fontsize, 
        SingleLetterItalics -> False]}, Spacings -> {0.4, 0.08}, 
      LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1}, LegendMarkerSize -> {22, 10}, 
      LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, 
          FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.5]], 
          RoundingRadius -> 5, Background -> White, 
          FrameMargins -> -1] &)]
```

This shows exactly what I am looking for but when I set the option `Joined` as `False` for a list in the `ListLinePlot`, the LineLegend changes automatically and insert a marker. Here is my setting for `ListLinePlot`:

```
plotbend = 
 ListLinePlot[{Range[0, 10], Range[0, 10]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {colors[[5]], {Dotted, Black}}, Frame -> True, 
  AspectRatio -> 1.1, Joined -> {True, False}, PlotMarkers -> None, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> Times, FontSize -> fontsize}, 
  FrameStyle -> Black, 
  FrameLabel -> {Style[
     "Normalized curvature, \!\(\*FractionBox[\(\[Kappa]\), \
SubscriptBox[\(\[Kappa]\), \(0\)]]\)", FontFamily -> Times, 
     FontSize -> fontsize], 
    Style["Normalized bending moment, \!\(\*FractionBox[\(M\), \
SubscriptBox[\(M\), \(0\)]]\)", FontFamily -> Times, 
     FontSize -> fontsize]}, ImageSize -> 360, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[leg, {0.73, 0.14}]]
```

Is it possible to make the `LineLegend` totally independent?

I am using Windows 10 and Mathematica 13.0.1.0.

Comment: What is `colors[[5]]`? And what `$Version` are you using? For my version 12.2.0, it shows `Spacings` in red color.

Comment: @Syed please see the edited post

Comment: use `Legended[ListLinePlot[...], Placed[leg, {0.73, 0.14}]]`

Comment: @kglr Thanks, that does the job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Legended`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended.html):

```
Legended[First @ plotbend, Placed[leg, {0.73, 0.14}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure that I have understood you correctly. If yes, I can propose a workaround. The idea is to add a third list  Range[0, 10]. For the first two you specify Joint->True, for the third Joint->False. Further, you specify the legend for the first two, and Legend->None for the third. Try this:

```
colors = ColorData[97, "ColorList"];

fontsize = 20;
leg = LineLegend[{colors[[5]], {Black, Dotted}}, {Style["simulation", 
    FontFamily -> Times, fontsize, SingleLetterItalics -> False], 
   Style["experiment", FontFamily -> Times, fontsize, 
    SingleLetterItalics -> False], None}, Spacings -> {0.4, 0.08}, 
  LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1}, LegendMarkerSize -> {22, 10}, 
  LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, 
      FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.5]], 
      RoundingRadius -> 5, Background -> White, 
      FrameMargins -> -1] &)];

plotbend = 
 ListLinePlot[{Range[0, 10], Range[0, 10], Range[0, 10]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {colors[[5]], colors[[5]], {Dotted, Black}}, 
  Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1.1, Joined -> {True, True, False}, 
  PlotMarkers -> None, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> Times, FontSize -> fontsize}, 
  FrameStyle -> Black, 
  FrameLabel -> {Style[
     "Normalized curvature, \!\(\*FractionBox[\(\[Kappa]\), \
SubscriptBox[\(\[Kappa]\), \(0\)]]\)", FontFamily -> Times, 
     FontSize -> fontsize], 
    Style["Normalized bending moment, \!\(\*FractionBox[\(M\), \
SubscriptBox[\(M\), \(0\)]]\)", FontFamily -> Times, 
     FontSize -> fontsize]}, ImageSize -> 360, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[leg, {0.73, 0.14}]]
```

returning the following:

[image]

Hope it helps.